# Cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'std::stack<_Ty>' to 'std::stack<_Ty> &'

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I am implementing a Visual C++ project and it use Windows forms. I need to use C++ stack and I used `stack<>`. But it gives this error. I include `#include <stack>` and `using namespace std;` Before adding `using namespace std;` it says undeclared identifier. But after adding that it gives this error. I am new to C++. Can anyone explain me why this happens. Thanks...!

Part of my Code:

```
stack<int> TA;
stack<int> TB;
stack<int> TC;

void move_a_to_b(){

  if(TB.top() < TA.top()){
     B[index_of_b + 1]->Image = A[index_of_a]->Image;
     B[index_of_b + 1]->Visible = true;
     A[index_of_a]->Visible = false;
     index_of_a--;
     index_of_b++;
     TB.push(TA.top());
     TA.pop();
  }
  else
     MessageBox::Show("Invalid Move","Error",MessageBoxButtons::OK,MessageBoxIcon::Exclamation);
}
```

Comment: Give us more to work with. Show the problematic lines.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use a `System::Collections::Generic::Stack<>`?

Comment: @delnan But there's clearly C++/CLI in the code, so I added the tag and asked the question.

Comment: @Marlon Different question then, what's C++/CLI about that code? I'm not an expert, maybe some class used shows it. But if so, I'd like to learn.

Comment: @Marlon I didn't know about it. What is the different between normal stack and that.

Comment: @delnan `MessageBox::Show`, `->Image`, and `->Visible` are all part of Windows Forms which means the OP is using C++/CLI.

Comment: @JKAUSHALYA `System::Collections::Generic::Stack<>` is the managed version of `std::stack`. Since it looks like you aren't working with native code (or are you?), you should use the managed version.

Comment: @Marlon Okay, nevermind (and I just noticed OP mentions Windows Forms too - silly me).

Comment: @JKAUSHALYA Just to make this clear to you, this is not C++ (and it isn't Visual C++ either, which is no language, but an IDE), it's C++/CLI, which is managed C++ for .NET and is a completely different language from C++. Being unaware of their differences and the additional "features" C++/CLI provides over C++ and over other .NET languages, is a perfect source for problems.

Comment: @JKAUSHALYA could you try replacing `using namespace std;` by `using std::stack;` ?

Comment: Could you post small but complete sample program that exhibits your problem? Also, it's probably not a good idea to write this program in C++/CLI. You should probably just use C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. This happens because of I am using unmanaged version of `stack` with managed version. the stack must not be initialized with the `new` keyword.